# How to draw shapes on maps using mouse in UWP xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, syncfusion, xamarin.uwp

I am working on UWP using Xamarin forms. I need a toolbar from which I can select a shape and draw that shape on the map manually by using the mouse. and that shape must be selectable.

Please provide me with any demo if possible since I am unable to achieve the solution with SF controls.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/finger-paint

Comment: Thanks but I need a toolbar and need to select a shape from that toolbar and draw that particular shape on map. e.g. like paint application

Comment: Yes, and that is a tutorial about drawing on the screen to help you get started.  Nobody is going to provide a complete solution for you that fits all of your requirements.  You need to break it up into pieces, learn how to implement each piece, and then how to combine them

Answer (score 0):

I have provided an alternative solution for interacting with the map through the following knowledge base link: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11962/how-to-interactively-place-the-markers-connect-and-drag-the-route-in-xamarin-maps-sfmaps

This knowledge base article provides detailed information on how to interactively place markers, connect them, and drag the route in SfMaps.